# ciclo foreach duplica las inserciones a la base de datos

Tags: php, json, postgresql, foreach

Tengo un JSON que lo envio desde una app android a un archivo PHP donde lo recorro y lo almaceno en la base de datos PosgreSQL, la situacion es que cuando son mas de 250 registros siempre los duplica ej json lleva 300 elementos e ingresa 600, los primero 250 los ingresa bien pero luego ingresa el 251 luego el 1 luego 252 luego el 2 y asi sucesivamente
obtengo el JSON

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

obtengo un JSON que va dentro del general:

```
$capturas = $obj->pl_capturas_insert;
```

y lo recorro:

```
foreach ($capturas as $key3 =>$value3) {
        $result3 = pg_query($dbconn,$value3) or die("falla captura");
        //$insertedCapturasArray[]=$key3;   
    }
```

Comment: VAs a tener que mostrar mas codigo. Aca no hay ningun error, y puede que el error este en la llamada o en algun otro lado...

Comment: De entrada, no está bien enviar consultas dentro de un bucle. Lo correcto sería construir primero toda la consulta y luego ejecutarla una sola vez. No es lo mismo desde el punto de vista del rendimiento hacer 250 ejecuciones que hacer una sola. Quizá convendría también que uses transacciones.

Comment: @A.Cedano pero si las 300 son insert a la base siempre tengo que usar un bucle? son 300 registros diferentes

Comment: No. Lo mejor sería construir una sola sentencia `INSERT` con los 300 registros y una vez construida ejecutarla. Algo como `INSERT INTO tabla (col1, col2) VALUES ('fila1-col1', 'fila1-col2'),  ('fila2-col1', 'fila2-col2'), ...` Antes de insertar puedes revisar la sentencia y si ves que en efecto se repiten datos debes verificar (en otra parte como apunta @gbianchi) por qué los datos se duplican.

Comment: ¿Esto para que es exactamente: `$capturas = $obj->pl_capturas_insert;`? ¿Qué es `$obj`? Observa que lo que estás usando para insertar es `$capturas`.... ¿depuraste ese objeto para verificar que no tiene datos repetidos? Si como parece el JSON se guarda en `$json` ¿por qué no lo conviertes a array y lo lees en el `foreach`?